run an async websocket loop in background of flask app
I am trying to build an app which will connect to a websocket (for streaming data) and provide this data with rest API. I am using Flask for creating my API and websockets package for connecting to websocket server.
This is my code so far:
import asyncio
import websockets
from flask import Flask, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)
websocket = None

async def websocket_setup():
    global websocket
    uri = 'wss://ws.example.com'
    websocket = await websockets.connect(uri)    
    print("WebSocket connected")

async def websocket_loop():
    global websocket
    await websocket_setup()
    while True:
        data = await websocket.recv()
        print("Received:", data) # will save to a global variable

@app.get('/')
def home():
    return jsonify({'msg':'hello'})
# Will have APIs for get data, send msg to websocket, etc

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.create_task(websocket_loop())
    app.run(debug=False)

error:
RuntimeError: no running event loop
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'websocket_loop' was never awaited

I am keeping websocket as a global variable, because I will need to use it in my API methods, like sending msg. I am okay to use any other framework also, I have tried with FastAPI and Sanic, but no success.

Hello, as the error is saying: all coroutines should be awaited. Function asyncio.create_task doesn't await couroutine. You should create a call asyncio.run(websocket_loop())

Thanks for the question.
Below is my draft version of the code that is getting information from the websocket and passing it to the Flaskapp.
What to pay attention here:

websocket job should be run in separate thread. Also consider using taskiq as a task broker if your code will become larger.
To communicate between main job and task job you can use Queue
You should pay attention to number of websocket processes created during app reloading in the debug mode. Basically my code will work fine in the production version, but may start duplicating threads connected to 'websocket'  if you use app reload.

import asyncio
import websockets
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from queue import Queue, Empty
from threading import Thread
import os
q = Queue()

app = Flask(__name__)

ws_uri = "ws://localhost:8000/chat/ws_proto"

async def websocket_loop(websocket):
    while True:
        data = await websocket.recv()
        print("ws data:", data) 
        # will save to a global queue
        q.put(data)

def ws_thread_task():
    async def ws_run(ws_uri=ws_uri): 
        # always run websocket in the context to properly close it on errors
        async with websockets.connect(ws_uri) as websocket:
            print("WebSocket connected")
            await websocket_loop(websocket)    

    asyncio.run(ws_run())


@app.route('/')
def home():
    print('connected')
    while True:
        try:
            item = q.get_nowait()
            print("recieved message", item)
        except Empty:
            print('q is empty')
            break        

    return jsonify({'msg':'data collection done'})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    # this options intended to prevent from creating duplicated threads on app reload
    if not (app.debug or os.environ.get('FLASK_ENV') == 'development') or os.environ.get('WERKZEUG_RUN_MAIN') == 'true':
        # start websocket job in separate thread
        thread = Thread(target=ws_thread_task, daemon=True )
        thread.start()

    
    app.run(debug=True, port=3333, use_reloader=True)


Thanks for helping. I have kept websocket as a global variable, because I need it in my subscribe API call. So, I need one route /subscribe?symbol=ABC, which will send some message on websocket for subscribing new symbols. And similarly /unsubscribe?symbol=ABC route.

you can't do both in one thread: do listen/recieve in websocket and listen for API calls to /subscribe. Thus two threads are required. And separate threads don't share global variables. Thus you either need to create memory sharable array between two threads. Or what is much easier add second Queue. If smn subscribes to a new symbol /subscribe?symbol=ABC you should do queue2.put({'action':'subscribe', 'symbol':'ABC'}). And of course websocket job should periodically check queue2 and process information from it.
